# Rails 3.1RC4 Mailer mail method returns wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a pretty standard mailer class with the following method:

```
def request(contact_us)
  @contact = contact_us
  mail(:to => "customercare@our_co.com", :subject => @contact.subject, :from => @contact.email)
end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

My first thought that is was the argument being passed in but some debugging/specs confirm the  error occurs on the line with mail(:to. The whole trace is below, line 9 is where the method is defined and line 11 is the mail method. I looked through the rails code and this is the method that's actually bailing in ActionView::Base

```
assign_controller(controller)
```

Any thoughts or suggestions? I have also tried RC5 with the same result.

Thanks!

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
    from /Users/user/Git/projects/app/mailers/notifier.rb:9:in `request'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_view/helpers/controller_helper.rb:15:in`assign_controller'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_view/base.rb:212:in `initialize'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:87:in`new'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:87:in `view_context'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in`_render_template'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:114:in `render_to_body'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:99:in`render'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:717:in `block in collect_responses_and_parts_order'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:728:in`each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:728:in `each_template'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:713:in`collect_responses_and_parts_order'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:652:in `mail'
    from /Users/user/Git/projects/app/mailers/notifier.rb:11:in`request'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in`process'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_mailer/old_api.rb:65:in`process'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:473:in `process'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:468:in`initialize'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:455:in `new'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:455:in`method_missing'
    from (irb):13
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in`start'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@projects/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in`require'

Comment: Please provide some more code around using your request method.

Comment: I ended up regenerating the mailer with different class and method names and that solved the problem. I'm not sure but on second though having a method called 'request' seamed a bit dangerous.

Comment: I've found both `request` and `notify` seem to cause problems

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It seems `ActionMailer::Base` doesn't like you use a `request` method for sending email. Change the method's name and it will work.

Comment: That's weird i got the same issue with method name `message`

Comment: See action_view/helpers/controller_helper, where the assign_controller method executes code that isn't applicable to ActionMailer.  ActionMailer::Base shares the ActionView code with ActionController::Base, but some code there assumes we're dealing with the latter.  Since request and config are used in assign_controller, they are bad choices for mailer method names.  For the same reason, some other bad choices for methods names are: `:request_forgery_protection_token, :params, :session, :cookies, :response, :headers, :flash, :action_name, :controller_name, :controller_path`

Comment: Yup. I was dealing with membership requests and the method being called `request` would return `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` on request.